# How to add only horizontal padding to a <td> with NO CSS

Tags: html-table, cellpadding

Is there a way to use cellpadding for just left and right? I am looking for answers but all I keep finding is CSS.

Comment: padding it a css property? Why do you not want to use it?

Comment: It's an emailer. I'd rather not use CSS.

Comment: I would say there isn't anyway without doing some hacks, if you check here there aren't many attributes to play with: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tr.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no clear way of doing with without position your `<td>` tag by using parent. Based on this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_td.asp there is nothing that is supported that will help.

I would suggest using attributes such as rowspan and colspan to help adjust table cells - using that will help you structure the content the way you want without having to use css.